# jquery cant understand $("input[name=arrayElement]).change

Tags: jquery, arrays, onchange

hi i have some code like this and it dont work, don`t show error too!!

I think there must be prob with array elements beacuase when i use of id it work! but i need element name, is there any solution?!

```
  $(document).ready(function() {  

       $("input[name=info[ind][3]]").change( function() {



     $("input[name=info[ind][1]]").val((( parseInt($('input[name=info[ind][3]]:checked').val()) * 1 +  parseInt($('input[name=info[ind][5]]:checked').val()) * 2 +   parseInt(0))  / 2 ));
                $("input[name=info[ind][1]]").trigger('change');
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):

> Attribute values in selector expressions must be surrounded by quotation marks.

Try the following (assuming the input name is `info[ind][3]`):

```
$('input[name="info[ind][3]"]')
```

Comment: when I execute this code `alert($('input[name="info[ind][5]"]').value) ;` it show me undefined but i have this elemet in my page and it has value too

Comment: @afsane Try the jQuery `val` function: `$('input[name="info[ind][5]"]').val()`

Answer (score 0):

Attribute values **must** be in double quotes if they're more than just a word. From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

> `value`: An attribute value. **Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string.**

*(Their emphasis)*

So:

```
$('input[name="info[ind][3]"]').change(...
```